# "Move to" and "Copy to" in SharePoint Online showing destination in A to Z order. Is there any way to change this so it displays Z to A?

Tags: sharepoint-online, move-to

Is there any way I can rearrange the way it is currently being displayed. [image]

It is currently showing me folder in A to Z format but I would like it to be Z to A format.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, The **Move or Copy panel** arranges the folders in **ascending order(A--Z)** by **Title**.

There is no way to sort the folders in **descending order(Z--A)**.